# How to get rid of brush opacity buildup in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

[image: example screenshot]

Left: a single stroke; right: two strokes with overlapping opacity. Is there any way to get rid of an opacity overlap on brushes that aren't already fully opaque?

Thank you

Comment: in example above you're using brush with `Wet Brush` option turned on: if your goal is to use this kind of brush without overlapping, it's not possible.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy alright, thank you

Answer (score 3):

draw ALL strokes with 100% opacity, at last lower opacity of the layer.